# How to create a proxy service to connect to Cloud SQL from GCP Composer

Tags: google-cloud-platform

This isn't a question, but an answer, if anyone has had the same struggle as me.

The problem: creating a SQL proxy server for GCP Composer to connect to Cloud SQL.

Google Docs (which won't provide you an answer): https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-kubernetes-engine

My solution: https://github.com/paulhtremblay/Google-Cloud-SQL-Composer-Proxy

Google docs and other resources on the Web were incomplete or outdated.

Comment: Edit your post into a question post and an answer post after reading this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Suggestion, always post a question with details. Sometimes what you assume to be **the** correct answer has an even better answer.

Comment: Edit your post into a question post and an answer post. Suggestion, always post a question with details. Sometimes what you assume to be the correct answer has an even better answer.

Comment: Are you sure this is related to [tag:composer-php] after all?